# How to echo a 3d array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I would like to sort my 3d array by the key "Value" then echo out the response. This is for a fraction game where people are suppose to place the fractions in order i have the fractions being generated but I need to echo out the array part by part like echo $data[0].

```
 $data = array(
    array('Value' => $even, 'PartA' => $Part1A, 'PartB' => $Part1B),
    array('Value' => $even2, 'PartA' => $Part2A, 'PartB' => $Part2B),
    array('Value' => $even3, 'PartA' => $Part3A, 'PartB' => $Part3B),
    array('Value' => $even4, 'PartA' => $Part4A, 'PartB' => $Part4B),
    array('Value' => $even5, 'PartA' => $Part5A, 'PartB' => $Part5B)
  );
 // function makeSortFunction($field)
  // {
    // $code = "return strnatcmp(\$a['$field'], \$b['$field']);";
    // return create_function('$a,$b', $code);
  // }

  // usort($data, makeSortFunction('Value'));
  sort($data);
var_dump($data);
echo "test" . $data[0][0] . "test";
```

Comment: this is only 2d unless the parts are arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to echo an arrays is

```
 echo print_r($array, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach($data as $v){

    foreach($v as $v2){
        echo $v2;
    }

}
```

Comment: If it truly is 3d, you need another for loop in there. In addition, if not all the attributes are arrays there needs to be a conditional to skip particular attributes